# Chromium without disable-web-security flag and cross origin for specific host

Tags: chromium, headless, websecurity

Working with `aws-chrome-lambda` lib, I'm using headless chromium to render data saved on S3 with presigned url.
I'd like to block access to local files and still be able to access the presigned url.

`aws-chrome-lambda` has `--disable-web-security` set up by default. I do want web security, so removing that to achieve blocking access to local fs. The problem is that it also blocks any other origin, thus I cannot access the data in S3.

I've also tried adding the flag `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` with the remote origin without success.
Running in a sandbox is not possible with this lib.

Any idea how to tackle it?